# Yahoo Mail: Hacking, Spoofing or Malware explosion

Tags: malware, spam-prevention, yahoo-mail, spoofing

It could be just coincidence, but in the week that my wife complains that here account has been 'hacked', I receive dodgy emails from most of the people I know who still use Yahoo accounts.

When my wife received reports from her contacts that they had received a dodgy spam email from her account, she logged in to check (she only uses the webmail interface). In her outbox, were two of the spam emails, but curiously they were marked as being sent to 'Recipients Unavailable' (or similar phrase). In my experience, whether you send emails to one person, several or a distribution list full of people, it will record this fact and allow you to view the details in your Outbox later.

When she raised this with me, I noticed that I'd had spam mails from a number of friends and family - all of whom were using Yahoo. I assume a similar thing has happened to them.

As far as we can tell, my wife's PC is clean, and she's changed the password to something else. But the fact that the recipients to these emails suggest that these emails originated from her (not-infected PC) nor from somebody/thing accessing her webmail directly, but from a third-party that either knew her credentials, or didn't need credentials.

Given that everyone I know with yahoo (that is, anyone who has one of my email addresses stored in their yahoo account) seems to be similarly affected, I assume it would be a big issue - but after googling, I've found no mention of any Yahoo problems beyond the usual ones.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: I’m disappointed this question was closed.  Other yahoo-mail questions have been allowed and I was curious to see whether people thought the account was compromised from the client PC or if the account was compromised from the site itself.

Comment: @CHarmon - that is precisely the point. I'm trying to find out (through other people's experiences) if this is likely to be a compromised machine, a compromised account or a weakly secured service. The irony is that the question seems amply catered for by the tags available.

Comment: I currently facing same situation for my yahoo mail account. Please note that I am unable to send any mail from it. I have put specific question at http://superuser.com/questions/609416/unable-to-send-mail-from-yahoo-mail-account-using-any-browser